# What is the pythonic way to avoid shadowing variables?

Tags: python, variables, scope

I often have the following code which either leads to variable shadowing or to a multiplication of local variables

```
def whenadult(age):
    return 18 - age

age = 5
needtowait = whenadult(age)
```

`age` has the same logical role both when passed to the function as in the main code so I would like to avoid creating something like `l_age` in whenadult.

What is the pythonic way to solve the *"shadowing vs. variable multiplication"* dilemma?

UPDATE: following up on some comments I want to make it clear that I was looking for a Python best practice (as opposed to local vs. global variables scope)

Comment: I'm confused - why would you need to create a l_age variable in the whenadult function?

Comment: Your problem doesn't lead to any multiplication of local variables, and I'm not even sure how it _could_.

Comment: (I will skip the "downvote without a comment" rant) -- what I meant is the creation of a new-named local variable (`l_age`) to avoid shadowing `age` as opposed to reusing the same names.

Comment: @WoJ: Presumably whoever downvoted you did so on the basis of one of the two existing comments (or on the other one that used to be there that someone later deleted). In that case, adding a "what he said" comment doesn't really add anything.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The fact that the local variable (and function parameter) `age` happens to have the same name as a variable somewhere else in your program is irrelevant. The whole point of local variables is that they only live within the local scope of the function they're defined in.

The fact that the local variable has the same name as the variable used elsewhere as an argument is *especially* not a problem. In fact, it's very common in real-life code. For example, picking a random stdlib module, the 3.3 version of `cmd`, the [`Cmd.onecmd`](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.3/Lib/cmd.py#l192) method has a variable named `line`, and it passes it as an argument to the `self.default` method, which binds it to a parameter that's also named `line`.

The fact that the variable used for the argument happens to be a global variable that you *could have* accessed, if you didn't have a local variable of the same name, is not a problem unless you actually wanted to access that global variable. Which you didn't want to in your existing code, and almost never *should* want to. In this case, and in most real-world cases, it's simply a coincidence that means nothing and affects nothing, not a problem you have to solve.

---

The problem you're having is that PyCharm can't guess whether you wanted the global `age` to be accessible in `whenadult`. Is it possible (if not in this trivial case, maybe in more complex cases) that a human might be similarly confused, slowing down his comprehension of your code? Or that you'll one day have to write code in some environment where your code reviewers or teacher or whatever will reject your code because it doesn't pass some linter with no warnings? Maybe.

But really, in any such environment, they'd probably complain about you using global variables in the first place. And you really don't need to here. The only reason `age` is a global is that it has to be accessible to the top-level code. If you move that code into a function, `age` can become a local in that function. For example:

```
def whenadult(age):
    return 18 - age

def main():
    age = 5
    needtowait = whenadult(age)

main() # possibly with an if __name__ == '__main__' guard
```

This will make PyCharm happy, and any linter tools, and any easily-confused or rigidly-minded human readers. It'll even make your code a tiny bit faster. On the other hand, it's more code to read—only three lines and one indent, but then the whole program is only eight lines long. So, it's a tradeoff that you can make on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: +1 I would add that a lot of IDEs will warn about shadowing variables to make sure you, the programmer, are aware. In my experience, it's usually the opposite scenario that creates bugs, where it was assumed the value from the outer scope is valid within a function.

Comment: @Fiver: my question came exactly from there: [PyCharm](http://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/) warned me about shadowing and I thought I would see if there is a pythonic way to tackle the point. I guess I should have made it clear in my question that I understand local vs. global variables and that I was wondering about best practices and not whether the code works or not (it works in both cases).

Comment: @WoJ: In this case, you really don't _intend_ to have any globals, it's just that your top-level code needs variables that are "local" at the top level. See my edit.

Comment: This does become a problem when you get multiprocessing involved. I have a function that randomly will pick up the global variable when it is set in if __name__ == '__main__': portion of the code, the function I use is called process_location, and I use a multiprocess pool for this. Very rarely, but it happens I have values from the next iteration of location being set in the previous. My code:

from multiprocessing import Pool

p = Pool()

for location in locations:
        p.apply_async(process_location, (location,), callback=call_back)

Comment: What if I want to use a variable from out scope, so I pass it as `var=var` to the function `def fun(var=var):` so that I can use it within `fun` scope, but Pycharm complains about shadowing again. I cannot even use `global` because the `fun` is defined in side another function, not in global scope.

Comment: @radtek It sounds like you have a race or other bug somewhere. If you're not intentionally sharing any globals, you may want to run your test suite with both the `fork` and `spawn` start methods (unfortunately, if you're using 2.x or an early 3.x, the only way to do that is to run on both *nix and Windows, which introduces other differences as well…); I'll bet it turns up an unintentionally-shared global.

Comment: @dashesy: You can always use `def fun(othername=var):` and use `othername` in the body to get the exact same effect. I personally think it's sometimes more readable with `var=var`, just as you obviously do and I think most Python programmers would agree with us—but again, linters have to be mechanical; they can't make the judgment call that in this case the readability benefits of the perfect name for the variable outweigh the potential costs of shadowing a name, so they just flag it. If you want to make your linter happy, you have to play by its rules.

Comment: @abarnert makes sense, I personally wait for linters (and Pycharm) to start using the type hints (perhaps in a `.pyi` file so that it works with 2.x) then will create `.pyi` files to help linters.

Answer (score 4):

PyCharm is going out of its way to prevent you from *accidentally* accessing(usually due to typos) a variable from the outer scope because doing so can create **really nasty bugs**.

**Short Answer:**
*Most* executables don't need to access the global state, so follow this structure that makes `main` a python function:

```py
def helper_function():
  # a function that will be used by main()
.
.
.
def main():
  # make MAIN a function.
  helper_function() 

if __name__ == '__main__':
  main() 
  # DONT define any variables here in this GLOBAL scope
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I got the warning of shadowing variable in PyCharm. I would try to rename the local variable to use the underscore prefix as the convention. That's another way to consider in addition to wrap global variables into a main() function.

```
    def whenadult(_age):
        return 18 - _age

    age = 5
    needtowait = whenadult(age)
```

Comment: prone to errors when you forget _

Comment: This will clutter a lot of code.